# Does Firefox still need "::moz-selection" to change background text colour in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

Is **::moz-selection** still required to change the text selection colour for Firefox? I've read a few articles who give the code below in order to change the text selection colour in my wordpress website.

```css
/* MP highlight text red */
 
/* For FireFox */
**::-moz-selection** {
background-color: #50BAEE;
color: #fff;
}
/* For everyone else */
::selection {
background-color: #E53333;
color: #fff;

}
```

I simulated the code above on browserling.com for Firefox. The colour selection was RED (not blue) in the browser.

FIREFOX TEST RESULTS: https://browserling.com/b/941baebc

Do I still need to use **::moz-selection** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::selection` and `::-moz-selection` are CSS psuedo-elements, which means their behavior depends on the browsers themselves independently of Wordpress, (unless Wordpress is somehow mangling your input files, but I have never heard of them doing such a thing.)

You can read more about them [on this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection), which contains the following information in the Syntax section:

```
/* Legacy Firefox syntax (version 61 and below) */
::-moz-selection

::selection
```

So whether you need `::-moz-selection` depends on how much you care about what users of Firefox version 61 and below see. You can see more information about browser support and usage numbers [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3A%3Aselection) as well.

Comment: Hi Ryan. That is what confused me - when I tested the css without ::-moz-selection, it worked on Firefox as shown in the TEST RESULTS. This is why I asked, do I still need -MOZ-SELECTION ?

Comment: If you were to try it without::-moz-selection on an old enough version of Firefox it wouldn’t work.  You can look at the second link in my answer and see an estimate of the percentage of people using those older versions. It’s a pretty small percentage so probably you don’t need it, but it’s ultimately up to you to decide how few people is few enough that you don’t care.